# Different results when training a model with same initial weights and same data

Tags: python, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to make some transfer learning to adjust the ResNet50 to my data set. 
the problem is when I run the training again with the same parameters, I get a different result (loss and accuracy for train and val sets, so I guess also different weights and as a result different error rate for the test set)
here is my model:

the weights parameter is 'imagenet', all other parameter value isn't really important, the important thing is they are the same for each run...

```
def ImageNet_model(train_data, train_labels, param_dict, num_classes):
    X_datagen = get_train_augmented()
    validatin_cut_point= math.ceil(len(train_data)*(1-param_dict["validation_split"]))
    base_model = applications.resnet50.ResNet50(weights=param_dict["weights"], include_top=False, pooling=param_dict["pooling"],
                                                   input_shape=(param_dict["image_size"], param_dict["image_size"],3))  
    # Define the layers in the new classification prediction
    x = base_model.output
    x = Dense(num_classes, activation='relu')(x)  # new FC layer, random init
    predictions = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)  # new softmax layer

    model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
    #   Freeze layers
    layers_to_freeze = param_dict["freeze"]
    for layer in model.layers[:layers_to_freeze]:
       layer.trainable = False
    for layer in model.layers[layers_to_freeze:]:
       layer.trainable = True
    sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=param_dict["lr"], momentum=param_dict["momentum"], decay=param_dict["decay"])
    model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    lables_ints = [y.argmax() for y in np.array(train_labels)]
    class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced',
                                             np.unique(lables_ints),
                                             np.array(lables_ints))
    train_generator = X_datagen.flow(np.array(train_data)[0:validatin_cut_point],np.array(train_labels)[0:validatin_cut_point], batch_size=param_dict['batch_size'])
    validation_generator = X_datagen.flow(np.array(train_data)[validatin_cut_point:len(train_data)],
                                   np.array(train_labels)[validatin_cut_point:len(train_data)],
                                   batch_size=param_dict['batch_size'])
    history= model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    epochs=param_dict['epochs'],
    steps_per_epoch=validatin_cut_point // param_dict['batch_size'],
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=(len(train_data)-validatin_cut_point) // param_dict['batch_size'],
    class_weight=class_weights)
    shuffle=False,class_weight=class_weights)
    graph_of_loss_and_acc(history)
    model.save(param_dict['model_file_name'])
    return model
```

what can make the output of each run different?
Since the initial weights are the same, it can't explain the difference ( I also tried to freeze some layers, didn't help). any ideas?

Thank!

Comment: Is the difference significant? It is expected to have tiny differences on each run.

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize the weights randomly in Dense layer, weights are initialized differently across runs and also converge to different local minima.

```
x = Dense(num_classes, activation='relu')(x)  # new FC layer, random init
```

If you want the output to be same you need to initialize weights with same value across runs. You can read the details on how to obtain reproducible results on Keras [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development). These are the steps you need to follow

1. Set the `PYTHONHASHSEED` environment variable to `0`
2. Set random seed for `numpy` generated random numbers `np.random.seed(SEED)`
3. Set random seed for Python generated random numbers `random.seed(SEED)`
4. Set random state for tensorflow backend `tf.set_random_seed(SEED)`